# Замена значения в столбце по значению другого столбца Pandas DataFrame по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, замена

Датафрейм:

```
      Match ID              Radiant               Dire  Winner
0   6808446343           beastcoast         Team Aster   False
1   6808199906              PSG.LGD        Team Liquid    True
2   6807837834              PSG.LGD                 OG    True
3   6808433308              TSM FTX        Team Spirit   False
4   6808416013               Fnatic             Entity    True
..         ...                  ...                ...     ...
95  6806101302         BOOM Esports                 OG   False
96  6806097565         BetBoom Team  Gaimin Gladiators   False
97  6806097974               Hokori            PSG.LGD    True
98  6806047119  Royal Never Give Up        Team Liquid   False
99  6806047605    Gaimin Gladiators       BetBoom Team    True

[100 rows x 4 columns]
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при значении False в столбце Winner выводилась ячейка Dire, а при True - ячейка Radiant? Пример ниже:

```
      Match ID              Radiant               Dire   Winner
0   6808446343           beastcoast         Team Aster   Team Aster
1   6808199906              PSG.LGD        Team Liquid   PSG.LGD
2   6807837834              PSG.LGD                 OG   PSG.LGD
3   6808433308              TSM FTX        Team Spirit   Team Spirit
4   6808416013               Fnatic             Entity   Fnatic
..         ...                  ...                ...   ...
```

Пытался таким куском кода - не вышло, ячейки не менялись вовсе:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df["Winner"][i] == "TRUE":
        df["Winner"][i] == df["Radiant"][i]
    elif df["Winner"][i] == "FALSE":
        df["Winner"][i] == df["Dire"][i]
```

Также были попытки через `.loc`, но не вышло: видимо где-то ошибся.

Прошу помощи :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно воспользоватьcя numpy.where()

если winner логическая переменная:

```
df['new'] = np.where(df['Winner'], df['Dire'], df['Radiant'])
```

Comment: Спасибо! Полностью решило мою проблему :)